# Why is Mockito giving me defaults for mocked objects?

Tags: mockito

In the following trivial exercise in my assertion I expect 1, but get 0. Why am I seeing this behavior?

```
public class MockitoTest {

   POJO mockedPojo;

   @Before
   public void setup() {
      mockedPojo = mock(POJO.class);
   }

   @Test
   public void testIndifferentMethodInvocationOrder() {
      int result1 = mockedPojo.getOne();
      assertEquals(1, result1);
   }

   class POJO {
      int count = 1;
      int getOne() {
         return count++;
      }
      int getTwo() {
         return count++;
      }
   }
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've mocked the entire class, which means that Mockito is providing the implementation and replacing yours.

Mockito's mock implementation of the class returns the default value for value types, which in this example explains why it is returning zero.

Generally, you'd not mock the class you are testing.  You usually use mocking to understand behaviour of the collaborators of an object.